# Basic resource on Japanese phonetics

Tags: phonetics, reference-request, japanese, resource-request

Could you recommend a good reference for studying Japanese phonetics?

Comment: Note that reference-request is meant for gathering resources on a topic but not for mere recommendations (even if I can see the two things are easily mistakable). I'm converting this to Wiki since it's sort of fundamental for the language.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a good book on Japanese phonetics:

Suski, P. M. [1931] 2011. [The Phonetics of Japanese Language: With Reference to Japanese Script](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lyUc7oNgaqoC). Taylor & Francis.

It's probably available at your library and there's a preview available on Google Books.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a great book: *"Грамматика японского языка. Введение. Фонология. Супрафонология. Морфонология"* by В. М. Алпатов, И. Ф. Вардуль, С. А. Старостин. That's the best piece I ever read on theoretical phonetics of Japanese.

The annotation:

> Данная книга представляет собой общее теоретическое введение к грамматике современного японского языка. Во вводной части определяются общие принципы построения грамматики, рассматривается строение языковой системы, в том числе фонологический, супрафонологический и морфонологический ярусы. В разделе «Фонология» описываются звуки современного японского языка, которые затем объединяются в фонемы; рассматривается фонемная структура слога. В разделе «Супрафонология» описана акцентуация современного японского языка. В разделе «Морфонология» рассматривается звуковая структура морфем и глоссем (слов) японского языка, неодинаковая в исконной и заимствованных подсистемах; описаны разные типы чередований.

Answer (score 0):

Let me please also to recommend some good interactive application, it is [**iPA Phonetics** *By John Esling*](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ipa-phonetics/id869642260?mt=8). While reading about *phonetics* we can notice, that we don't know the pronunciation of some special symbols: for ex. how to pronounce `"ʐ"` or `"ɸ"`..? In this case, I strongly recommend this **free application**. It is easy and very useful to work with.

Description:

> This APP provides a unique and intuitive touch interface for exploring
>   the International Phonetic Alphabet as well as numerous voice
>   qualities and articulations. Simply press any symbol or label in the
>   charts to see and hear an illustrative example. Test your knowledge by
>   playing the random guessing games. Amazing laryngoscopic and
>   ultrasound videos accompany sounds articulated in the throat! You can
>   speed up and slow down all the video examples, view full-screen, and
>   more! Press the INFO button on each screen to access additional
>   information.